# Como consumir api json com javascript?

Tags: javascript, webforms

```
   [
        {
            "_id": "5c31047849793040d06003f2",
            "title": "Amanda e Anderson",
            "slug": "Adicionar",
            "price": 58
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c3104aa49793040d06003f3",
            "title": "PPP",
            "slug": "deu certo",
            "price": 4550
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c31160849793040d06003f4",
            "title": "Anderson",
            "slug": "1020",
            "price": 6580
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c312ea726e54829504df6f6",
            "title": "Paulo",
            "slug": "Adiconar",
            "price": 22.9
        }
    ]
```

O objetivo é buscar as informações com JavaScript e adicioná-las dentro do *TextBox* do *C#*

Comment: *Como eu busco essa informação via javascript*, quer dizer como pesquisar uma informação dentro desse `json`?

Comment: Buscar em JavaScript e o trazer dentro do TexBox do C#.